# How can many Puddle Slimes can be in a pond together without blushing?

Tags: slime-rancher

I am storing my Puddle Slimes in the Dock's natural pond, but they have been blushing and refusing to store plorts. This is detrimental to my success as a rancher, so I would like to know: how can I avoid blushing and the refusal to produce plorts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have four Puddle Slimes producing Plorts in the same pond, or five with a Rubber Ducky.

Comment: My pond doesn't seem to have a Rubber Ducky, although the wiki says the Docks come with one.

Comment: The docks don't come with a rubber duck, it is a slime toy unlocked via the 7Zee Rewards Club.

Comment: Apparently they aren't spawning because "they don't spawn in games created before the 0.5.1 update, in which the second day has passed." according to [this page](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_Toys#Trivia) on the [Slime Rancher Wikia](http://slimerancher.wikia.com/).

Comment: Despite the fact this was from three years ago, I'll mention this anyway for those coming from the future. When you unlock The Docks expansion to your ranch (This is past The Overgrowth), at least in the PC edition, I usually find a Rubber Ducky in the pond that has a waterfall going into it. So, you can get one before joining the 7Zee Rewards Club if you are rich enough.